# CSS for my SVG (Having trouble with Transform Origin)

Tags: css, svg

So I have two classes(firstCircle & spin) on the First circle on the left and I'm trying to get it to rotate in place.(removed them from css so you can see the circle) I'm getting confused on transform-origin: What is wrong with my code.It's rotating way out of place instead of spinning. I added a width and height and tried transform-origin and it just makes it disappear.

```
.spin {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 120px;
height: 1120px;
margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
-webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
-moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
transform-origin: center center;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

```css
.container { padding:auto;

width: auto;
height: auto;
text-align:center; }

.line1 {
 stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 10s linear forwards;
   animation-delay: 2.13s;
}
.line2 {
 stroke-dasharray: 1000;
 stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
 animation: dash 10s linear forwards;
 animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.line3 {
 stroke-dasharray: 1000;
 stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
 animation: dash 10s linear forwards;
 animation-delay: 3s;
}
.line4 {
 stroke-dasharray: 1000;
 stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
 animation: dash 10s linear forwards;
 animation-delay: 3.4s;
}
.line5 {
 stroke-dasharray: 1000;
 stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
 animation: dash 10s linear forwards;
 animation-delay: 3.9s;
}
@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
   stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}


.insidefirstCircle {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 100;
 animation: insideCircle  10s linear forwards;
 animation-delay: 1.2s;
 
}
@keyframes insideCircle {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    opacity: 1;
    
  }
  to {
   stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   opacity: 1;
  }
}

.secondCircle {
 animation: secondCircle  2s linear forwards;
 animation-delay: 2.2s;
}

@keyframes secondCircle {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    opacity: 0;
    
  }
  to {
   stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   opacity: 1;
  }
}

.insidesecondCircle {
 animation: insidesecondCircle  2s linear forwards;
 animation-delay: 2.2s;
}

@keyframes insidesecondCircle {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    opacity: 0;
    
  }
  to {
   stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<svg>

   
    <path class="firstCircle spin"
       transform="matrix(-0.98886073,0.14884376,-0.16522036,-0.98625668,0,0)"
       d="m -28.957516,-109.01346 a 20.505369,19.487934 0 0 1 25.9801488,5.74848 20.505369,19.487934 0 0 1 -1.9792854,25.281519 20.505369,19.487934 0 0 1 -26.5892124,2.031123 20.505369,19.487934 0 0 1 -6.202719,-24.656512"
       id="path7158"
       style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:0.94117647;stroke:#4fae7d;stroke-width:0.35702455;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1" />
    <path class="insidefirstCircle"
       transform="matrix(-0.22033261,-0.9754248,-0.97735568,0.21160309,0,0)"
       d="m -102.55362,-32.142649 a 7.185163,7.442451 0 0 1 5.829705,7.489633 7.185163,7.442451 0 0 1 -6.173275,7.188196 7.185163,7.442451 0 0 1 -7.86062,-5.124812"
       id="path7160"
       style="opacity:0;fill:none;fill-opacity:0.94117647;stroke:#4fae7d;stroke-width:0.35700712;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1" />
    <ellipse class="secondCircle"
       ry="5.8064542"
       rx="5.806459"
       transform="rotate(-9.0228844)"
       cy="102.10918"
       cx="31.181959"
       id="path7162"
       style="opacity:0;fill:none;fill-opacity:0.94117647;stroke:#4fae7d;stroke-width:0.38561434;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1" />

       <circle class="insidesecondCircle"
       r="2.081239"
       style="opacity:0;fill:none;fill-opacity:0.94117647;stroke:#4fae7d;stroke-width:2.138;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="circle7192"
       cx="46.80978"
       cy="95.955421" />
    <circle class="line1"      
       r="8.1839027"
       cy="124.84148"
       cx="88.252518"
       id="path7166"
       style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:0.94117647;stroke:#4fae7d;stroke-width:0.63219434;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1" />
    <circle 
       style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:0.94117647;stroke:#4fae7d;stroke-width:3.454;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="circle7168"
       cx="88.252518"
       cy="124.84148"
       r="4.5812778" />
    <circle 
       r="6.7396846"
       style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:0.94117647;stroke:#4fae7d;stroke-width:0.52063066;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="circle7174"
       cx="128.74611"
       cy="90.168755" />
    <path
       style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:0.94117647;stroke:#4fae7d;stroke-width:0.35702455;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="path7186"
       d="m -180.38976,-169.87182 a 20.505369,19.487934 0 0 1 27.64196,8.28339 20.505369,19.487934 0 0 1 -8.68637,26.27924 20.505369,19.487934 0 0 1 -27.66048,-8.22736 20.505369,19.487934 0 0 1 8.62739,-26.29677"
       transform="matrix(-0.98886073,0.14884376,-0.16522036,-0.98625668,0,0)" />
    <ellipse 
       style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:0.94117647;stroke:#4fae7d;stroke-width:0.35702455;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="ellipse7190"
       cx="152.20651"
       cy="155.0309"
       transform="matrix(0.98886074,-0.14884364,0.16522023,0.9862567,0,0)"
       rx="5.5144606"
       ry="5.2409396" />
    
    <circle 
       cy="90.168755"
       cx="128.74611"
       id="circle7196"
       style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:0.94117647;stroke:#4fae7d;stroke-width:2.13800001;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1"
       r="2.081239" />
    <path class="line1"
       id="path875"
       d="m 19.085467,74.174836 c 22.366283,17.178223 22.335724,17.75844 22.335724,17.75844"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#4fae7d;stroke-width:0.28233331px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
       <path class="line2"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#4fae7d;stroke-width:0.36648375px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 51.183439,99.59881 c 29.032633,22.29825 28.992966,23.0514 28.992966,23.0514"
       id="path885" />
    <path class="line3"
       id="path879"
       d="M 95.534634,121.46865 C 123.9702,95.423153 123.73736,94.872744 123.73736,94.872744"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#4fae7d;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
    <path class="line4"
       id="path881"
       d="m 134.621,93.468564 c 37.14699,33.672096 37.14699,33.672096 37.14699,33.672096"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#4fae7d;stroke-width:0.26971px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
    <path class="line5"
       id="path883"
       d="m 181.40295,129.52127 c 31.40453,-10.83262 31.9066,-11.93052 31.9066,-11.93052"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#4fae7d;stroke-width:0.37912115px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
    
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/osvnnmtk/

Comment: Here is a fiddle of it with the css and no transform origin

Comment: SVG 1.1 has a limited set of CSS styles that it supports. While SVG2 expands the set, there is limited support for these in current browsers. Generally you have to use Javascript (e.g. snap) to animate within an SVG.

Comment: so you're saying it's not possible to do with my current code without java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, most of the CSS properties you have in your `.spin` and `firstCircle`  definitions are invalid.  `position`, `top`, `'left`, and `margin` are all HTML-only properties. And `width` and `height` are not valid for `<path>` elements.

It is important to remember that SVG is a totally different standard from HTML and works differently.

Secondly, your path already has a `transform`. CSS transforms don't add, so any `transform` in your animation, will overwrite the one on your `<path>`.

The simplest way to resolve that problem is to either (a) get your SVG editor to multiply through the transform to the path coordinates; or (b) work around it by using a nested group `<g>` element around the path. One of the transforms is applied to that, and the other is applied to the path.

```
<g transform="matrix(-0.98886073,0.14884376,-0.16522036,-0.98625668,0,0)">
  <path class="firstCircle spin"
        d="..." />
</g>
```

**transform-origin**

Now that those issues are resolved, we can deal with the matter of the centre-of-rotation.

There are issues with browser compatibility with `transform-origin`. Chrome has an implementation that is out-of-date with respect to the specification. That is in the process of getting fixed, but for now, the workaround is to always use absolute coordinates instead of percentage values.

The centre of your circle is at `(-19.5, -91.7)`, so the correct `transform-origin` to use is:

```
transform-origin: -19.5px -91.7px;
```

So if we plug this into a working example:

```css
.spin {
  transform-origin: -19.5px -91.7px;
  animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
  100% { transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<svg>

  <g transform="matrix(-0.98886073,0.14884376,-0.16522036,-0.98625668,0,0)">
    <path class="firstCircle spin"
          d="m -28.957516,-109.01346 a 20.505369,19.487934 0 0 1 25.9801488,5.74848 20.505369,19.487934 0 0 1 -1.9792854,25.281519 20.505369,19.487934 0 0 1 -26.5892124,2.031123 20.505369,19.487934 0 0 1 -6.202719,-24.656512"
          style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:0.94117647;stroke:#4fae7d;stroke-width:0.35702455;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1" />
  </g>
  
</svg>
```